# I can't screenshot on Steam?

Tags: steam

I've been able to screenshot ever since I got Steam but now when I tried to screenshot my game it didn't work. I have Steam overlay enabled and the overlay comes up but when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> it doesn't work.

I tried <kbd>Fn</kbd> with everything still nothing. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What changed that caused the screenshots to stop working?

Comment: and is Fn + F5 the shortcut to screenshot? http://i.imgur.com/QuGxI.jpg

Comment: @Aequitas - I take it 'Fn' is the option that enables the Function keys on the OP's laptop, as they are probably default to media keys. Bucky - have you tried just pushing 'F5' without the 'Fn' key?

Comment: If I recall correctly, F12 is the default `Take Screenshot` key - worth trying that (or `fn+F12`)?

Comment: @Robotnik usually it's the other way around, pushing just f5 will send F5, while pushing fn+f5 will do something else like lower volume or whatever but yes it depends on the laptop, besides the default is F12 so they've either changed it or not pushing the right Fkey at allat all. Without them saying more info it's impossible to tell, that's why I've voted to close.

Comment: @Aequitas - Yeah you're right it depends on the laptop brand. Some even have the ability to toggle the default depending on how you prefer to use them. It might be worth adding that last part of your comment as an answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> is just the button to activate some options on some laptops. Try to change the screenshot's actual key in Steam:

1. Click on 'Steam' on the top of the window

[image: Steam dropdown menu on top of window]

2. Go into the Settings
3. Under the In-game tab, change the value under 'Screenshot activation key'

[image: Settings menu with screenshot activation key highlighted]

Change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Hi TailsXGames, please remember to **[give images proper descriptions](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7470/28182)**. The text you provide will be displayed if the image is unavailable, and it is read out loud by screen readers to describe the image for the vision impaired. :)