# Why are my attempts to take in-game screenshots (in Big-Picture mode) failing?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, napoleon-total-war

I recently purchased NTW, and am now interested in taking some in-game screenshots. I am not hearing a click when I press F12 (the Screenshot hot key reported by Steam), and am not seeing any screenshots either from within Steam or on disk. I am led to believe that the screenshots should appear somewhere below the directory:

```
%UserProfile%\Pictures\Screenshots\
```

**Environment:**

- Windows 10 on AlienWare 15 laptop
- Running on *LG Widescreen* monitor (2560x1080) from *Nvidia* graphics card in full-screen mode (NOT windowed)
- NTW launched from *Steam Big Picture*

This was tentatively closed as a duplicate, but as a complete newbie to Steam I found this answer to be much more informative than the linked possible duplicate. Combined, they filled in a lot of details about the relationship between Big Picture and normal that I had been unaware of. I believe treating both questions as related but not duplicates is appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't screenshot on Steam?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237226/i-cant-screenshot-on-steam)

Comment: I disagree, @BanhMiDacBiet . This is from a game launched with Steam Big Picture, which has different rules and controls than the main client.

Comment: While using steams big picture mode and in game, can you still do `shift + tab` to see the Steam overlay? If you press F12 and then access the overlay, are your screenshots in the bottom left?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf only in appearance. Functionality is the same still. I updated the image in my answer to the big picture equivalent. Instead of setting a folder, you are required to use the screenshot notification window to choose between cloud upload or saving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your Steam Preferences and select the "In-Game" option.

Check your shortcut keybind and set them appropriately. Make sure the notification is enabled. When you screenshot, a notification will appear and you can turn on the Overlay to view the screenshot and upload/save where you want it to.

[image]

Comment: The asker is questioning about Steam Big Picture, not the main client.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The changes in Big Picture are minimal.

Comment: The process is entirely different... don't try to tell me that the changes are minimal, but then edit your answer to be for Big Picture. Nice try.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I updated my answer appropriately and do not believe the process is entirely different. The difference between the settings page is the inclusion of the screenshot folder option. In Big Picture you're required to use the notification window.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Big picture is same client, it's a different, "controller friendly" minimalistic mode of GUI for same program.