# How can I re-enable the city card displayed when double-clicking a city?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, napoleon-total-war

I was playing around with the settings [after setting up my screenshot capability](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293984/why-are-my-attempts-to-take-in-game-screenshots-in-big-picture-mode-failing), and now the card that should pop-up when I double-click a city is not showing. There are hot-keys to several other cards, but I cannot find one for this card, and there doesn't seem to be a control to disable this pop-up. What have I done wrong?

**Environment:**

- Windows 10 on AlienWare 15 laptop
- Running on *LG Widescreen* monitor (2560x1080) from *NVidia* graphics card in full-screen mode (NOT windowed)
- NTW launched from *Steam Big Picture*

[image: In-game settings]

**Update**:

I discovered that the cards can still be retrieved by right-clicking on the Capital from the Region List card; but it was nice to be able to double-click the Region Capital as well.

Comment: Are you talking about the info city card that show you detail of how everything is break down or the entire city card itself? Just a tiny clarification.

Comment: @Vyndicu: I can still access the Building list card, showing the build upgrades. I cannot see the card that showed up when I double-clicked a Region Capital on the Campaign Map, outlining the details of tax income, town wealth, popular support, etc. I do still see the little 2-line summary overlay for the Region Capitals.

Comment: There is a checkbox if I recall for that on the left city building card. It has been a LONG time since I last play napoleon TW but that is what I recall. It has been nearly true for most of TW titles since then.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I kept playing, and a couple of hours later the Region Capital cards started appearing again on double-click. Maybe it was just a glitch rather than an inadvertent setting change.